# How can I export MIT App Iventor apps to IOS?

Tags: ios, apk, ipa, app-inventor

MIT App Inventor allows to create apps for android only. But I have created a complex app to calculate Motorgrader Performance that I want to share in Android and IOS also.
SO, I need a way to export that app (.aia) to IOS.

I tried to convert the apk file to .ipa but it doesn't work.

Comment: According to MIT App Inventor docs, you ***cannot*** generate an iOS app for App Store distribution - only AdHoc. Quick look at their forums and they *may* be working on it.